# последний пробел Pascal

Tags: pascal, geany

Почему то что бы я не делал, не удаляются все пробелы с конца в данном коде. в данном примере удаляются только два последних пробела.

```
program untitled;
uses crt;
var i, j: integer;
    l:string;
BEGIN
    i:=0; j:=0;
    write('type: ');
    readln(l);
    for i:=0 to length(l) do begin
        while (l[length(l)]=chr(32)) and (l[length(l)-1]=chr(32)) do begin
            delete(l,length(l),1);
            j:=length(l);
            dec(j);
            l[length(l)]:= l[j];
        end;
        while l[1] = chr(32) do delete(l,1,1);
        while (l[i] = chr(32)) and (l[i+1] = chr(32)) or (l[i] = chr(32)) and (l[i-1] = chr(32)) do
            delete(l,i,1);
    end;
    writeln(l);
END.
```

Comment: Что должен делать этот код? Опишите словами. Пример входных данных? Ожидаемый выход? Получаемый выход?

Comment: @Igor Очевидно, он удаляет лишние пробелы. входные данные - любая строка с пробелами. Ожидаемый выход - та же строка, в которой отсутствуют пробелы в начале, в конце, и между словами ровно 1 пробел. На деле выполняются все условия кроме одного: с конца строки удаляется только 2 пробела при данном коде.

Comment: И зачем вы поставили вопросу метку geany ?

Comment: @Kromster не разводи флуд. Нет предложения по решению - проходи мимо.

Comment: Я у вас спросил конкретный вопрос. Если не можешь ответить по существу, то *"не разводи флуд"*, а просто убери лишнюю метку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки в Паскале нумеруются с единицы, поэтому цикл с нуля - неверен. Удаление крайних пробелов внутри цикла `for` смысла не имеет, можно вынести наружу.
После возможного удаления длина строки не перепроверяется, будут выходы за границы строки.

Если скорректировать выбранный подход, то он может выглядеть примерно так:

```
 while (length(s) > 0) and (s[length(s)]) = ' '
    Delete(s, length(s), 1);
 while (length(s) > 0) and (s[1]) = ' '
    Delete(s, 1, 1);
 spos := Pos(s, '  ');
 while spos > 0 do begin
    Delete(s, spos, 1);
    spos := Pos(s, '  ');
 end;
```

Более эффективно же  не долбить строку постоянными перераспределениями, а один раз пройти по ней, "выжимая" лишнее:

```
  procedure NormalizeSpaces(var s: string);
  var
    i, deleted, len: Integer;
    space, newspace: Boolean;
  begin
    space := True;  //для удаления пробелов в начале
    deleted := 0;
    len := length(s);
    for i := 1 to len do
    begin
      newspace := (s[i] = ' ');
      if space and newspace then //пробел не первый
        Inc(deleted)
      else 
        if deleted > 0 then  
          s[i - deleted] := s[i]; //переписываем символ на его конечное место
      space := newspace;
    end;
    if (len > 0) and space then
      Inc(deleted);  //последний пробел 
    SetLength(s, len - deleted); //один раз изменим длину
  end;
```